# SCDF launching spring batch Pod in kubernetes : Pod resource utilization

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

Apologies if this is a duplicate question - I looked out for similar ones but did not find exactly what I was looking for.

Here is the situation :

I have to upload file and run spring batch to process the file. So I have a Spring boot MS which accepts the file uploaded request and calls SCDF(spring cloud data flow), which then, launches a POD for the batch job in kubernetes. As many files uploaded so many pods created. Right now each pod is having same amount of resources given through properties configured. But these are static properties:

spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.cpu=1
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.requests.cpu=800m
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.memory=2Gi
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.requests.memory=1Gi

The memory consumed by pods has two parts :  m = c+ f(n). m is memory actually consumed by pod. c is size of the image - each pod has to get image deployed inside it. f(n) is a function of no of records (n) present in file. My target is to have optimal resource utilization - So what is the best solution for this scenario?
I understand SCDF stream with kafka is one - anything else with SCDF batch ?

Comment: Hi All - I am trying to see if the following approach has an optimal solution for the given problem:

Comment: It is usually the best to start with low requests values and no limits. Then monitor the resource usage over time with a known load and then adjust the limits accordingly,